# Square brackets as label in tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd

I found that I could not use square brackets as label of arrow when using tikz-cd package to draw commutative diagram.
A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzcd}
        Z \arrow[r,"[1]"]& X
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

I got the following error:

> Argument of \tikz@quote@@parser has an extra }. ^^I\end{tikzcd}

If I use instead `\arrow[r]{[1]}`, I get no error but the brackets are not showed in the pdf.

I looked through the documentation of tikz-cd and failed to find the reason.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Did you try `\arrow[r,"{[1]}"]` in order to “hide” the inner bracket?

Comment: That  works indeed! Thank you.